# How to submit form values in lowercase?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a combobox in a form, written in html, like following:

```
<form name="formname" action="formaction.php" method="get">
    <select name="selectname">
        <option>Option1</option>
        <option>Option2</option>
        <option>Option3</option>
    </select>
    <!-- other inputs -->
</form>
```

Upon submission, an example url would be "formaction.php?selectname=Option1".  I wish for the option value to be passed in the url as "option1", but I want to avoid having a `value` attribute for every option, equal to the option's innerHTML (I've considered doing this dynamically via JS as well).  Note: I already process values server-side without regard to character case; I want to do this simply for aesthetics.

**My goal is to submit all form values in their lowercase representations.**

I've attempted adding an `onsubmit` attribute to the form with `state = state.toLowerCase()`, and similar forms like referring to the value via the document element, retrieved by id.

Is this possible, or must I dynamically set each option's `value` attribute to its lowercase form?

Comment: why not process the values on the server side?

Comment: @AndreDublin I already process values server-side case insensitively.  While it might sound a bit OCD, I only am looking for this answer to keep the url entirely lowercase, as I believe `key=value` looks far cleaner in a URL than `key=Value`.

Comment: I see, it looks as if Ibu's css solution may be your best bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no native method in javascript that sets all your forms value to lower case.

You can just as easily process those values on your server side and turn them to lowercase. or you can print them as lowercase in your html and use css to show them as first letter uppercase:

```
<select name="selectname">
        <option>option1</option>
        <option>option2</option>
        <option>option3</option>
    </select>

select option {
   text-transform:capitalize;
}
```

Comment: What happens if someone views this with css disabled, or through a text viewer?

Comment: @MartinLyne Good point, but that shouldn't be an issue, because the data is handled case insensitively on the server side.  It'll just look a little odd aesthetically (with options in lower case) for css-disabled users, but I sure hope my forum-centered website doesn't have any css-disabled users.

Answer (score 0):

If you really *must* do this on the front-end then I'd recommend using something like jQuery to find all your inputs in a page `$('input')` (thought, server-side should usually be your first port-of-call, or even better, just use `<option value="lowercaseversion">Upper Case Version</option>` when forming your HTML.

But, client-side solution, cll this function before teh form is submitted:

```
myLowerCaser()
{
 $('input').each(function(i, input)
 {
   input.val(input.val.toLowerCase())
 }
 return true;
}
```

Replace the "input" with a more specific selector if you want it to only affect certain things (like JUT the combobox would be `$('select.selectname')`

Comment: I attempted that solution already (as I say in my question) using the `onsubmit` attribute to no-avail. However, I didn't try doing so in the `onclick` attribute of the submit button. I also explained in my question that I don't want to set the value of each option to the lowercase value of what is displayed. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: The question has changed considerably since I saw it :-)

Comment: The only change in the question since its posting was that I added the note about server-side being irrelevant.